# MySQL SELECT Query - Subtract a SUM() value with the combined total of two other SUM() values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two SELECT statements that give the values "TotalSales" and "VendorPay_Com". I want to be able to subtract VendorPay_Com from TotalSales within the one MySQL statement to get the value "Outstanding_Funds" but I haven't found a reliable way to do so.

These are my two statements:

Query 1:

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
FROM PROPERTY
WHERE Status = 'Sold';
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT SUM(AC.Amount) AS VendorPay_Comm
FROM (
SELECT Amount FROM lawyer_pays_vendor
UNION ALL
SELECT CommissionEarned AS `Amount` FROM COMMISSION AS C WHERE C.`status` = 'Paid') AS AC
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
select (select ...) - (select ...)
```

In your example, simply :

```
select 

(
SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
FROM PROPERTY
WHERE Status = 'Sold'
)
-
(
SELECT SUM(AC.Amount) AS VendorPay_Comm
FROM (
SELECT Amount FROM lawyer_pays_vendor
UNION ALL
SELECT CommissionEarned AS `Amount` FROM COMMISSION AS C WHERE C.`status` = 'Paid') AS AC
) AS Outstanding_Funds
```

Comment: Thank you very much Grisha! Worked perfectally :)

Comment: Thanks bro! You save my time ++

Answer (score 1):

Try

```sql
SELECT TotalSales-VendorPay_Comm AS Outstanding_Funds
  FROM
(SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
   FROM PROPERTY
  WHERE Status = 'Sold') t1, 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) AS VendorPay_Comm
   FROM (SELECT Amount FROM lawyer_pays_vendor
          UNION ALL
         SELECT CommissionEarned AS Amount 
           FROM COMMISSION
          WHERE Status = 'Paid') t0) t2
```

Here is **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7028d/4)**